# Short text taking up 2 lines

Tags: html, css

I'm finding that on mobile, short text that i know can appear in just 1 line is taking up 2 lines.

I've found that "white-space: nowrap" will make sure that it will appear in 1 line. However, now I have a problem where long text that is supposed to take up 2 lines is now forced to appear in 1 line, which is a problem.

What's causing this issue and how do I solve it?

It's the third Lorem Ipsum

```
  <div class="name">Lorem Ipsum </div>
```

That's causing this problem

What I want is that text that's supposed to take up 1 line (or 2 lines) take up just 1 line (or 2 lines).

```css
.grid article {
  position: relative;
}

.students {
  position: absolute;
}

.person {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin,
  padding: 0px;
}

.name {
  letter-spacing: 2.2px;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.picture {
  flex: 0 0 28px;
  margin: 0;
}

.person img {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media (min-width: 1312px) {
  .students {
    top: 565px;
  }
  .name {
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 2.2px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .person img {
    width: 28px;
  }
  .person {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 599px) {
  .students {
    top: 375px;
  }
  .name {
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 2.2px;
    margin-left: 6px;
  }
  .person img {
    width: 21px;
  }
  .person {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<article>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(img/image.png);"></div>
  </a>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="one">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="two">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
  <div class="students">
    <div class="person">
      <div class="picture"><img src="img/sample.jpg"></div>
      <div class="name">Lorem Ipsum </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Grid Layout CSS

```
.grid {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;  
  display: grid;
  justify-content: start; 
  margin-top: -20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
} 


.grid article {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 250px;
}


.grid .photo {
  width: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}

.grid .photo:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.grid a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;

}

.grid a:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.grid .text {
  margin: 0px;
}

    
@media (max-width: 599px) {

  .grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(140px, 1fr));
  grid-row-gap: 140px;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  } 

}
```

Comment: Re: _"I'm not sharing code"_ - then we don't know what HTML element(s) you're using or how they're styled.

Comment: *I'm not sharing code* Then we don't share answer

Comment: I've updated the post with code

Comment: It is impossible to tell without looking at your code, but it is likely a problem with encoding. Try typing that text manually. If it solves the problem then it is definitely the encoding.

Comment: If you are referring to the third Lorem Ipsum then it is because the image is occupying part of the container's width.

Comment: @WaisKamal Yes I'm referring to the third one.  How do I fix that?

Comment: I am not that familiar with grid layout, but generally you have to increase the width of the container that has the image and text in it.

Comment: Hm I wouldn't want to change the size of grid items (which are <article>s here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need the image to be next to the text on mobile?

If you want them to stay aligned then just add `flex-direction: row;` to your person class in the `@media (max-width: 599px)` and set a max-width on your `picture` and `name` div that doesn't exceed 599px.

If you want them to stack then just add `flex-direction: column;` to your person class in the `@media (max-width: 599px)`

*Note:* You may need to adjust width depending on how much text you want next to your image so it doesn't wrap when it hits the width threshold on mobile.

See snippet below.

```css
.grid article {
  position: relative;
}

.students {
  position: absolute;
}

.person {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin,
  padding: 0px;
}

.name {
  letter-spacing: 2.2px;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.picture {
  flex: 0 0 28px;
  margin: 0;
}

.person img {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media (min-width: 1312px) {
  .students {
    top: 565px;
  }
  .name {
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 2.2px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .person img {
    width: 28px;
  }
  .person {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 599px) {
  .students {
    top: 375px;
  }
  .name {
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 2.2px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .picture {
    width: 21px;
    max-width: 21px;
  }
  .person {
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<article>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(img/image.png);"></div>
  </a>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="one">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="two">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
  <div class="students">
    <div class="person">
      <div class="picture"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/28/11/08/castle-5693094__340.jpg"></div>
      <div class="name">Lorem Ipsum </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need the image and text to be next to each other

Comment: See the updated snippet, instead of using `flex-direction: column` use `flex-direction: row` and put a max-width on your image/text that doesn't exceed 599px

Comment: wow thanks.  just adding flex direction: row & setting max width for picture alone did the job.

Comment: This works because you are using flexbox styling in your CSS. The parent container around your picture/image has a `display: flex` declaration. The items within this container are flex items. - You can change the way they are displayed with flex-direction. We are also applying max-width to account for the media query you have declared, since 599px is the max-width for that specific view, we want to contain the items inside so they don't exceed that amount.  More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction